# PHP Ratchet Websocket Symfony, stash data in session?

Tags: php, symfony, sockets, session, ratchet

I'm doing websocket server to game and i have problem to stash information about users. I write event listener which run special event according to first incoming packet in message. Everything works OK but i don't have idea how stash the data about clients...
I'm try to use session but all time, my variables not stored in session.

Command to run server ( i'm try memcache and PDOSession storage ):

```
<?php
    /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->writeln('Server starting');
    $communication = $this->getContainer()->get('uo_server.server_communication');

    $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.01;dbname=uo-session', 'root', null);
    $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbOptions = array(
        'db_table'        => 'sessions',
        'db_id_col'       => 'sess_id',
        'db_data_col'     => 'sess_data',
        'db_time_col'     => 'sess_time',
        'db_lifetime_col' => 'sess_lifetime',
        'lock_mode'       => 0
    );

    $sessionProvider = new PdoSessionHandler($pdo, $dbOptions);

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new SessionProvider($communication, $sessionProvider),
            2593,
            '127.0.0.1');

    $server->run();
}
```

Message component looks like:

```
    function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->packetDispatcher = $container->get('uo_server.packets_event_dispatcher');
    $this->connections = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * When a new connection is opened it will be passed to this method
 * @param  ConnectionInterface $conn The socket/connection that just connected to your application
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
{
    $this->connections->add($conn);
    /**
     * @var Session $session
     */
    $session = $conn->Session;
    $session->setId('session_'.$conn->resourceId);
    $session->start();
}

/**
 * This is called before or after a socket is closed (depends on how it's closed).  SendMessage to $conn will not result in an error if it has already been closed.
 * @param  ConnectionInterface $conn The socket/connection that is closing/closed
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
{
    $conn->Session->save();

    if($this->connections->contains($conn)) {
        $this->connections->removeElement($conn);
    }
}

/**
 * If there is an error with one of the sockets, or somewhere in the application where an Exception is thrown,
 * the Exception is sent back down the stack, handled by the Server and bubbled back up the application through this method
 * @param  ConnectionInterface $conn
 * @param  \Exception $e
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
{
    $conn->Session->save();

    // TODO: Implement onError() method.
}

/**
 * Triggered when a client sends data through the socket
 * @param  \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $from The socket/connection that sent the message to your application
 * @param  string $msg The message received
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg)
{
    $this->packetDispatcher->dispatchEvent($conn, $msg);
    $conn->Session->save();
}
```

Packet dispatcher is simply:

```
    public function dispatchEvent(ConnectionInterface $sender, $msg)
{

    $data = unpack('C*',$msg);
    $eventPacket = "0x".DataConverter::convertDecimalToHex($data[1]);
    $event = isset($this->packetsEvents[$eventPacket]) ? $this->packetsEvents[$eventPacket] : null;

    if ($event !== null) {
        $incomingEvent = new MainEvent($sender, $msg);
        if ($this->dispatcher->hasListeners($event)) {
            $this->dispatcher->dispatch($event, $incomingEvent);
        } else {
            Logger::Log('Event :'.$event.' is not implement yet!');
        }

    }
}
```

at least the example login event:

```
    public function onLogin(MainEvent $event)
{
    $this->event = $event;
    $packetReader = new PacketReader($this->event->getMessage());
    $login = $packetReader->getByteFrom(2, 30);
    $password = $packetReader->getByteFrom(32, 30); //todo some byte on the end?

    if($this->accountFinder->checkAccountAccess($login, $password)) {
        Logger::Log('try to log:'.$login . '/' . $password.';');
        $account = $this->accountFinder->getAccount($login, $password);
        return $this->loginSuccess($account);
    }

    if($this->serverInfo['auto_account'] && $this->accountFinder->checkAccountExist($login) === false) {
            Logger::Log('account not found, but autoaccounting is on. Account created;');
            $account = $this->accountFinder->createUser($login, $password);
            return $this->loginSuccess($account);
    }

    Logger::Log('login for credientals: '.$login.'/'.$password.' failure;');
    $this->loginFailure($login);
}

private function loginSuccess(Account $account)
{
    $ip = explode(".", $this->serverInfo['host']);
    $packet = new Packet;
    $packet
        ->prependPacket("A8")
        ->appendPacket("FF")
        ->appendPacket(DataConverter::convertDecimalToHex(1), 4)
        ->appendPacket(DataConverter::convertDecimalToHex(1), 4)
        ->appendPacket(DataConverter::convertStringToHex($this->serverInfo['name']), 64, Packet::PAD_FROM_RIGHT)
        ->appendPacket(DataConverter::convertDecimalToHex($this->serverInfo['full']), 2) //todo full is not from PARAM!!!
        ->appendPacket(DataConverter::convertDecimalToHex($this->serverInfo['timezone']), 2);
    for ($i=3; $i>=0; $i--) {
        $packet->appendPacket(DataConverter::convertDecimalToHex($ip[$i]), 2);
    }

    $currentLenght = $packet->getPacketSize();
    $packet->injectPacket(DataConverter::convertDecimalToHex($currentLenght + 2), 4, 2);
    $this->event->setToSession('accountId', $account->getId());
    $this->event->getClientSession()->save();
    $this->event->getClient()->send($packet->getPacket());
    return true;
}

/**
 * TODO FAILURE FROM BANS ETC.
 * @return bool
 */
private function loginFailure($login)
{
    $reason = 0;

    if ($this->accountFinder->checkAccountExist($login)) {
        $reason = 3;
    }

    $packet = new Packet;
    $packet
        ->prependPacket("82")
        ->appendPacket(DataConverter::convertDecimalToHex($reason), 2);
    $this->event->getClient()->send($packet->getPacket());
    return true;
}
```

When i try to read the session in next event, it's not exist. Looks like new session start, but files and session in database not exist (its not created). It's possible to storage data like this ? If not, what alternatives i had?

link to repo with full code:
[REPO](https://gitlab.com/elanon/uoserver)